# Change the height of a row in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I want when a user clicks a row, that row grows to show more items with an scale animation, but I can't find how can I do that.

I don't know how can I change a height row at runtime. I've tried making the items visible, but this didn't work even if I inflate with another XML layout.

If I achieve the first one, I think I could make the scale animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained well in [APIDemos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List6.html) itself. Check the Collapsed List Adapter in ApiDemos/Views/Lists/6. ListAdapter Collapsed.

Comment: Do you know how can I put an scale animation to the height of the row when it expands?

Comment: @Adrian: Check the same ApiDemos/Views/Layout Animation/List Cascade.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find that apidemo, could you tell me when it is?

Comment: Check this link: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LayoutAnimation2.html

Comment: I think this is not I am looking. Something similar is how the notification list grow or shrink when you drag the bar a bit. I want that when a user clicks in a row, that row expands with the same animation like notification bar but I don't know if that is possible.  Also, I have a problem with the rows. When I click one, it changes its size without problems, but then it can't be clicked again to returns her old size. It seems that become unclickable because doesn't appear the higlight color over the row. Thanks for everything.